# hard disk names changed in 16.10

Tags: lubuntu, 16.10, devices

Yesterday I updated to kernel 4.8.0-28.
After booting today, by sata hard disk names start with /dev/sdb, not /dev/sda. sda is not used at all.
Is this related to the new kernel?

I found this in dmesg:

```
[    4.590048] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE     0817 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    4.590585] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    4.590643] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    4.592206] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

But I do not have removable disks, only usb sticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Udev may have just recognized them in a different order if there was a change in udev at all. You can control this behavior as well if you look up using udev to name devices. This is also the reason for other distributions such as Fedora switching naming conventions to enp9999s99 naming conventions for devices.